# Is $\lfloor2\sqrt{n-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}\rfloor <\lfloor2\sqrt{n} \rfloor$ true for $n\geq 0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have reasons to believe that $\lfloor2\sqrt{n-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}\rfloor <\lfloor2\sqrt{n} \rfloor$ for $n\geq 0$. How could I go about proving (or disproving) this?

Comment: I am afraid, you have accepted the answer too earlier. All you have to do is to change $<$ with $\leq$.

Comment: Did you even try $n=0$ !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by checking the inequality for small values of $n$. You would find that it is false already for $n=2$.

Comment: For $n=2$ LHS=RHS, it's a corner case, other than that, [it seems true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(2*sqrt(x-floor(sqrt(x))))+-floor(2*sqrt(x)))

Comment: @rtybase: there are infinitely many equalities. See my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, true ... I am not sure if that's what OP was after (strict $<$ or $\leq$). $n=0$  is easier to check than $n=2$.

Comment: @rtybase: non strict is immediate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then $n=0$ (from $n\geq0$) is a counter example and we should probably close the question as "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: @rtybase: I don't think so. You are hypothesizing that the question could be with $\le$. But as its stands, there is no ambiguity: it is wrong. The OP should indeed have observed that it doesn't work with $n=0$ (which he willingly included in the domain).

Answer (score 2):

$$\lfloor2\sqrt x\rfloor$$ is a non-decreasing function so it is obvious that

$$\left\lfloor2\sqrt{n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\right\rfloor\le \lfloor2\sqrt n\rfloor$$ holds.

The interesting cases are equality, i.e.
$$\left\lfloor2\sqrt{n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\right\rfloor=\lfloor2\sqrt n\rfloor.$$

The function $\lfloor2\sqrt x\rfloor$ remains the constant $m$ for

$$m^2\le4n\le(m+1)^2-1.$$

So we need

$$m^2\le 4(n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor)\le m^2+2m.$$

As
$$\left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor\le\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor\le\left\lfloor\frac {\sqrt{m(m+2)}}2\right\rfloor,$$ by addition and taking the tightest bounds,

$$m^2+4\left\lfloor\frac m2\right\rfloor\le 4n\le m^2+2m,$$ which is not void for even $m$.

Every $m=2k$, i.e. $n=k(k+1)$ makes the equality, as

$$k(k+1)-\left\lfloor\sqrt{k(k+1)}\right\rfloor=k^2$$ and

$$\left\lfloor2\sqrt{k(k+1)}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor2\sqrt{k^2}\right\rfloor=2k.$$

There are no other solutions.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1) ... to a badly formulated question

Comment: @rtybase: I was fearing that the inequalities couldn't be sorted out. But in the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. It is true if you replace $<$ with $\leq$ and use the fact that

> **Proposition.** If $x\leq y \Rightarrow \lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor y \rfloor$

---

From that proposition, $\forall n\geq 0$ 
$$0\leq2\sqrt{n-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \leq 2\sqrt{n} \iff \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \geq 0$$
and as a result

$$\lfloor2\sqrt{n-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}\rfloor \leq\lfloor2\sqrt{n} \rfloor $$